# Which type of array to use for large amounts of numbers?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, performance

I need to store large amounts of `unsigned char`s and/or `int`s (potentially 100,000,000 and up) in an array. Mathematical operations will frequently be performed on the numbers in this array, so the array will be modified often, and the length of the array can potentially change often as well.

I can use C or Objective-C (or both). Performance wise, would it be better to use a plain C array and `realloc` it as necessary, or just go for an `NSMutableArray`? Or does anyone have any better ideas?

**Please note** that performance is my main concern, I am willing to write extensive reallocation code if necessary.

**Also:** Memory usage is a consideration, but not a concern (as long as it doesn't end up using multiple gigabytes).

Comment: The reallocation code doesn't need to be extensive: `int *data = 0; size_t size = 0, capacity = 0;` sets up an empty array (or use a struct, of course). Then to ensure a certain capacity: `if (capacity < required_capacity) { size_t new_capacity = max(capacity*2, required_capacity); int *tmp = realloc(data, new_capacity*sizeof(*data)); if (!tmp) { handle error; } else { data = tmp; capacity = new_capacity; }`. Some people prefer to use `capacity*3/2`, or some other approximation to the square root of 2, rather than doubling capacity. Either way, I've omitted the essential check for wraparound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `NSMutableArray` means you have the overhead of two Objective-C message sends every time you want to get or set the value of an array element.  (One message to get the element as an object, and a second to get its value as a primitive `int`.)  A message send is much slower than a direct array access.

You could use a `CFMutableArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray`, and specify callbacks that let you store bare numbers instead of objects.  But you would still need to use a function call to get or set each array value.

If you need peak performance, just use a plain C array, or a `std::vector` if you want to use Objective-C++.

Comment: If I use a plain C array, what's the best way to go about `realloc`ing? How expensive a call is it? Is it better to allocate more than you need to save time?

Comment: You need to increase the array by a factor (multiplication) rather than a fixed amount (addition) each time you reallocate it.  E.g. `newSize = oldSize * 2`, **not** `newSize = oldSize + 100`.

Comment: your array is tiny. 10000 ints is nothing. Allocate more than you need and grow generously if you have to.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Looking through my code, I realised 2 things:
1. I can't count.
2. It'll be more like 100,000,000 numbers.
Still tiny?

Comment: @robmayoff How bad for performance is using `realloc` to shrink the array?

Comment: @NightLeopard That's 380MB. If you try to allocate continguously with a bunch of reallocs then you will fragment your heap. That's going to be a problem in a 32 bit process. One way around that is not to allocate contiguously and use an adaptor layer to make non-contiguous blocks appear like a single array.

Comment: Regarding performance - you'll have to profile your code to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Will your array need to grow much and how much ?
Using `realloc` is not very performant.

That's why I would recommend a linked list as you can find `GSList` in [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html).

Comment: linked lists don't sound right here. No random access. Plus access is slow with all the extra cruft. On 64 bit system the list overhead is bigger than the list itself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Using `realloc` is fine, as long as you don't do it often. If you double it whenever you need to enlarge, and just don't shrink it, it will be very fast (and may waste memory).

Comment: @ugoren indeed so, that's exactly my opinion

Answer (score 0):

The **container**:
How about C++? Objective-C++ and STL might be a point, STL was made by smart people and it's actually quite efficient in skilled hands. Although, having potentially up to 100,000,000 entries requires some optimization tricks in any cases.

The **framework**:
You haven't specified the task itself, could it be suitable to use something like CoreData or maybe SQLite? The math can be done with SQL procedure.

The first one is good if you have some, mmm, data samples - pixels, audio chunks or something like that. The second way is definitely preferred in most other cases.

Comment: There's no SQL database or anything like that. The data could potentially come from anywhere - it could be loaded from a text file, or spontaneously produced at runtime. Basically, it normally starts off short and then gets bigger and bigger as more numbers are added and mathematical operations are performed.

Comment: Than I'd choose STL. std::vector is smart enough to avoid re-allocation on every push, STL allows to use functors to process the data, inlining results fast code. Overall, it worth trying and (IMHO) is preferred over Objective-C and plain C arrays.

Comment: Another advantage of using standard C++ containers is that if memory fragmentation does cause problems (as noted by David Heffernan in a comment on rob mayoff's answer), then the "optimization trick" to fix it is usually trivial -- just switch from `std::vector` to `std::deque`.